# Telling Mercurial about the moved files after a major re-organization

Tags: mercurial

We recently re-organized a very unorganized site on our server at work. This website is version controlled using Mercurial. We re-organized everything. Thousands of files. Now when I do a `hg status` it shows a ton of new untracked files represented by a `?` and tons of missing files, which are the same files as the untracked ones, represented by a `!`.

How do I tell Mercurial that we moved these files? I know I can do it one-by-one, but this isn't an option given that there are thousands of them.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use `hg mv --after` to signify you have already moved the file.

Comment: Also `hg mv --after` can take wild cards so if large groups of files are moved from one directory to another it can be handled with one command.

Comment: How do I check that this was recorded properly? It seems `hg status` doesn't show renames.

Answer (score 26):

`hg addremove` will detect renames after-the-fact if the files are 100% similar by default, and the similarity threshold can be overridden with `-s`.

Also, if using TortoiseHg, `thg guess` will bring up a dialog where you can use a slider to set the similarity and view the resulting matches between added and deleted files, then select the pairs you want to record as a rename.

Example:

```
C:\>hg init test
C:\>cd test
C:\test>echo >file1
C:\test>echo ONE>file1
C:\test>echo TWO>file2
C:\test>hg ci -Am init
adding file1
adding file2

C:\test>ren file1 file3
C:\test>ren file2 file4
C:\test>hg st
! file1
! file2
? file3
? file4

C:\test>hg addrem
removing file1
removing file2
adding file3
adding file4
recording removal of file1 as rename to file3 (100% similar)
recording removal of file2 as rename to file4 (100% similar)

C:\test>hg status -C   # -C shows file copies.
A file3
  file1                # file3 copied from file1...
A file4
  file2                # file 4 copied from file2...
R file1
R file2
```

Comment: Thanks for TortoiseHg tip of `Detecting Renames`... +1

Answer (score 14):

Use `hg addremove`. You can't just move files around and expect Mercurial to know about that —  if you're moving tracked files, use `hg mv`.

Comment: +1. Notice that `hg mv` forces Mercurial to track the history of a file whereas using `hg addremove` you suppress a fact of file moving/renaming.

Comment: Just to reiterate: With `addremove`, you create a situation where a file just appears out of the blue, without history which it in fact had prior to the rename. Try sticking to `hg mv`.

Comment: @Helgi, @keykeeper, `hg addremove` will detect renames after-the-fact.  See my answer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Good you explained that, thanks. In my experience, though, such "re-organizations" often imply modifications of many of the renamed files.

Comment: Please have a look at Steve Losh post about it : [Addremove Can Track Renames But Won’t Unless You Ask It Really Nicely](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/05/what-i-hate-about-mercurial/#addremove-can-track-renames-but-won-t-unless-you-ask-it-really-nicely). It looks like you have to use an explicit `similarity` option : `hg addremove --similarity 100`