# Teaching a mercurial repository about a bad rename after it is pushed

Tags: mercurial, revision-history

We have moves and renames of files in our published mercurial history that were not properly recorded, so that they appear in the history as unrelated deletions and adds.
Is there any way to tell the repository about the connections so that `--follow` commands can work again?

*(For non-pushed changes, [here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841212/telling-mercurial-about-the-moved-files-after-a-major-re-organization) discussing how to get mercurial to properly record moves/renames before you commit, as well as a useful tip [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/05/what-i-hate-about-mercurial/#addremove-can-track-renames-but-wont-unless-you-ask-it-really-nicely).)*

Comment: I didn't see this related question while editing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945914/fixing-renames-in-a-mercurial-repository-after-committing   Those answers might be what I need, but I haven't thought through yet whether they are a good idea for changes going way back in the history.  (Will it work straightforwardly to do something like that and merge into the tip?)

Comment: Just merge (maybe with special `internal:???` tool) "bad rename changeset" after correcting commit (it'll appear as additional head) before pushing

Comment: My question is about correcting for pushed and shared changes.  Imagine the mistake was made years ago.

Comment: OK. **Two** mergesets (without rewriting history) instead of one... for *any* amount of descendants of bad changeset

Comment: Have you tried making another branch from the original changeset (before the rename), recording the rename there, and then merging with that? "follow" would then follow two distinct paths, one path would be along the path towards the bad merge, the other would bypass it and follow the rename. Not sure you'd get the changesets in the right order though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works but is a bit brutal: You can login remotely on your central Mercurial server, fix the renames there as a local change and then ask everyone to clone the repo again.

This works since all Mercurial repos are equal. You just think of one as "central" but in fact it's a repo like any other. So if you have access to that, you can rewrite history there. The drawback is of course that every developer will notice, so they'll have to export any non-pushed changes they made, clone the repo again and then import the patch.

**[EDIT]** A possible workaround would be to create a new branch just before you did the bad rename, rename the files properly and then cherry pick all the changes after that into the new branch.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to merge this branch into your original branch. If you did, then Mercurial would see two kinds of file renames in the past and I'm not sure which one it would follow.

So before you merge, I suggest that you create a small test/demo repo where you reproduce the situation and then try it out.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, it's good to note the brutal solution exists, and sometimes that may be the best solution.  For my question I really want to know though if there's a way --follow can be fixed with additional changesets way down the tree.

Comment: No. [Mercurial creates cryptographic hashes over changesets](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html). If you change a single bit in the author, message or content of a changeset, then the hash changes and pulling from this repo will break for everyone else.

Comment: I don't want to modify any published commits.  I'm wondering if an *additional* new changeset can provide information mercurial needs to follow back to changes before the rename.

Comment: I had another idea how you could do this. See my edits.

Comment: I'm planning to try something similar to that in a test-repository, and I'll report back after I get a chance to do the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new head from before the rename, do the rename properly, then merge it into the head from the upstream server. It will give you a conflict. When this happens, revert the offending files to the revision from your new head (with the good renames; `hg revert -r <rev> <files...>`).